# How to stop all cores and run my code (in kernel space) on all the cores, in FreeBSD?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, scheduler, freebsd, multicore

In FreeBSD kernel, how can I first stop all the cores, and then run my code (can be a kernel module) on all the cores? Also, when finished, I can let them restore contexts and continue executing.

Linux has APIs like this, I believe FreeBSD also has a set of APIs to do this.

---

### edit:

Most likely I did not clarify what I want to do. First, the machine is x86_64 SMP.
I set a timer, when the time is over; to stop all the threads (including kernel threads) on all cores; save context; run my code on one core to do some kernel stuff; when finished, restore the context and let them continue running; periodically. The other kernel threads and processes are not affected (without changing their relative priority).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your "code" (the kernel module) actually takes advantage of SMP inherently already.

So, one approach you can do is:

- Set the affinity of all your processes/threads to your desired cpus (`sched_setaffinity`)
- Set each of your threads to use Real-Time (RT) scheduling.

If it is a kernel module, you can do this manually in your module (I believe), by changing the scheduling policy for your task_struct to `SCHED_RR` (or `SCHED_FIFO`) after pinning each process to a core.

In userspace, you can use the FreeBSD `rtprio` command (http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rtprio&sektion=1):

`rtprio, idprio -- execute, examine or modify a utility's or process's
     realtime or idletime scheduling priority`

The effect will be: Your code will run first before any other non-essential process in the system, until your code finishes.